# Pandas can not locate .xlsx file. Is there a way I can make it work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to load data from an excel file using pandas for some reasons python cannot load my data.

```
kg = pd.read_excel('C:\Users\Desktop\NewData','Sales')
```

> SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes
>   in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape***

Comment: try `pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\Desktop\NewData\file.xlsx')` since \ is an escape character in python, you can also try `pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\\Desktop\\NewData\\file.xlsx')`

Comment: Thank you for your input bro.. But nothing has changed.

Comment: Generally your desktop is under `r"C:\Users\{UserName}\Desktop\NewData\file.xlsx"'` - because Users collects all users of your PC .... it should be easy to verify your files location if you use the windows explorer - navoigate to it and copy the correct path ...

Answer (score 1):

Because of escape parameters, python is trying to comprehend '\U' from the path as a unicode character. To avoid that try to ad r which means raw before your string to stop the string formatting. OR just use '\' for each '\' as the string formatting takes two backslashes to retrieve one back slash. ex:

```
kg = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\Desktop\NewData','Sales')
```

or

```
kg = pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\\Desktop\\NewData','Sales')
```

Comment: I have tried that but i still get ***FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Desktop\\NewData.xlsx'***

Comment: add the file extension.

Comment: Thank you @justice_Lords.  It returns **False**. The file does not seem to exist from python viewpoint.

Comment: Thank you all for your contributions. Issue has been been resolved; all I did was to save my .ipynb file in the same location as the .xlsx file.